# How do I get JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a website that has pages with JSON data. At least I think so.
When I write something extra(group=11 and like that) to link it shows only on webpage with JSON data. Like this:

```
{
    "Week": "2011-04-09",
    "Class": [{
        "Name": "ARK",
        "Number": "30"
    }, {
        "Name": "PER",
        "Onenr": "34"
    }]
}
```

How can I get this data to another site? I've tried jsonCallback but so far nothing(XMLHttpRequest cannot load...). I have some knowledge about JSON but I still dont know how to do it. Help me, please.

Comment: Use AJAX with `contentType` set to `JSONP` if you are going to retrieve that data from another website.

Comment: @Cyval: But only if that site actually serves JSONP.

Comment: If that site doesn't serve JSONP, set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header on that site to the domain of the site where you're running the JSON AJAX call.

Comment: When you say "get this data to another site", do you mean server side or client side?

Comment: I'm going to structure this data and make it available on a website. I think it's client side then? :)

Comment: Google "Acces-Control-Allow-Origin" to learn how to allow cross-domain AJAX.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker so I'm not sure if I wrote the question as supposed to be. The site I'm taking data from is not mine.